# Altering Structure order doesn't update cache

Tags: structure, cache, navigation

I have 2 structures that are used for Menus on the site. Each entry is a link to either an entry / asset or external URL. The hierarchy is used to generate a menu .

To save on page load time, the two menus are both wrapped up in `{% cache globally %}` tags which has worked really well to speed up things.

My problem is that when altering the position / hierarchy of the structure entries from Craft, the front-end doesn't update accordingly which I can only put down to the cache blocking the update, as the structure isn't re-triggering the cache update.

Any tips for long term maintenance on this site feature? Some of the content editors will want to alter this stuff, but without disabling the cache myself? The only user that can manually flush the template cache is myself, the admin.

Thanks in advance y'all!

Merry Christmas! :-)

Comment: BTW I have removed the cache tags for now, which allows them to make the changes, but I'd like to discuss this point to see what another alternative would be. Thanks

Comment: How does your cache tag look like? Just `{% cache %} content {% endcache %}` without attributes?
Do you notice any stuck background tasks in the Craft admin panel when you using cache tags?

Comment: Yes I did notice there are stuck background tasks for cache in the admin! And yes that is how the cache tags are structured. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Greg Stewart's help I found that the reason that the Cache wasn't updating when altering the hierarchy of the Structure is:

**There were Stuck background tasks.**

[Here is the official documentation on the matter.](https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks)